# Branch cut of $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}}{1+x}$

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, contour-integration, branch-cuts

Why do I need to use a branch cut from $0$ to $\infty$ when evaluating $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}}{1+x}$?

I know there is a pole at $x=-1$

I can't seem to understand the purpose of the branch cut? Is it because if i write $f(x) = \frac{x^{s-1}}{1+x}$, $f(|x|) \ne f(|x|e^{i2\pi})$

Comment: Because for most values of $s$ the function $z\to z^{s-1}$ is not defined without a branch.

Comment: Could you please tell me why that is true?

Comment: Because by definition $z^w=e^{wlog(z)}$. And logarithm requires a branch.

Comment: @pablo_mathscobar- You can also think of this as the fact that whenever $s-1$ is not an integer, $z^{s-1}$ will not be continuous at the branch you're cutting out. And for most values of $s$, $s-1$ is indeed not an integer

Comment: Does the presence of the pole have anything to do with the need for a branch cut or is it just the fact that there is an exponent on the z

Comment: Yes you can describe the domain of analyticity of $f(z) = \frac{z^{s-1}}{1+z}$ with $f(z e^{2i \pi}) = e^{2i \pi (s-1)} f(z)$ and $f$ is locally analytic everywhere else except a simple pole at $z=-1$. Thus there is a unique branch of $f$ which is analytic on $\Bbb{C}- [0,\infty) - \{-1\}$ and $\lim_{y \to 0^+} f(1-iy) = 1/2$. And $z=0$ is a branch point because $f(ze^{2i\pi}) \ne f(z)$ this is why you need branch cuts. Try with $g(z) = z^{1/2}$ to see how branches and path-dependent analytic continuation really works with those things

Comment: $f(ze^{2i\pi})$ means analytic continuation after one ccw rotation around $z=0$ not just plugging $z e^{2i\pi}$ instead of $z$